# Dual OS configuration

Tags: linux, operating-systems, administrator, window, default-settings

I have installed windows and Linux(ubuntu) on the same machine. Now the problem is when I start my machine, It directly goes to Linux and not asking me for the selection of OS either I want to load Windows or Linux. How can I change setting that it ask me for the selection of OS.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**NOTE:** I want to know settings for both cases either system directly loads windows or linux , what will be the settings to make it selected from user.
Thanks